# convert sqlite values into pdf format

Tags: android, sqlite, pdf, android-external-storage

I have done income/expense application in android studio.Am using SQLite database,In that there are two tables namely income and expense which contains the value of description and the money what they spent or earned in a particular day or month.The thing i need is ,if the user want to take the pdf format of particular month or day's report they can able to download it in that format.am stuck in here.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

So you can fetch data from your SQLite database and write it in a PDF. Then you can download that PDF to the user's device. For creating PDF in android programmatically, you can follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34296596/1649353.