# how to save all data of listview in text format on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-api-levels

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

i am new in android programming please guys help me.That how to save all data of Listview in text format on button click in our mobile

```
 static String[] city = {"Indore","Bhopal","Mumbai","Pune","Delhi","Kolkata",
        "Hyderabad","Banglore","Chennai","Amritsar","jhalandhar"};

Button button;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

    MyAdapter myadapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),city);
    listView.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

Comment: hows your listview looking?

Comment: it simple a list of city name @android_griezmann

Comment: i have edit the question @android_griezmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code on your button's click

```
try {
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
            myOutWriter.append(city[i] +"\n");    
        }

        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Note : Don't forget to give below permission in `AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: thank you sir let me check whether it is working or not

Comment: Thank you So much sir its working thanks a lot and sir hoe to save it in PDF format

Comment: Welcome, and use [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34296596/3800164) for creating PDF, It's bit tricky!

Comment: i am not able to understand how to convert in PDF format @android_griezmann

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
        ListViewItem item = items.get(i);
        edit.putString(Integer.toString(i), item.elementOne + "," + item.elementTwo + "," + item.elementthree);
    }
    edit.commit();
```