# convert fragments content to pdf file

Tags: android, pdf, share

I have developed a simple android application that is story creator, and I used fragments as story pages.
Is there any way that I can convert these pages to PDF file then share it by email?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your story content can be stored as file and after of it you can share your file throgh share Intent.

[Creating a pdf file in android programmatically and writing in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296149/creating-a-pdf-file-in-android-programmatically-and-writing-in-it)