# Trying to create a PDF from a listview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-pdf-api

Hello Everyone I'm trying to create a pdf programatically from a set of images. I'm loading images on Listview from array list. after displaying the images on click floating action button I'm willing to create a new PDF file. I'm successfully creating file, Unfortunately I can able to see only one image on the pdf file out of 5 images. For reference purpose here I'm sharing the code which I'm trying to achieve. Please help me in creating and displaying list of images on PDF

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;

public class DisplayPreview extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = DisplayPreview.class.getName();

    ListView imagesLV;

    FloatingActionButton fabPDF;

    TextView tv_link;
    ImageView iv_image;
    LinearLayout ll_pdflayout;
    public static int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    boolean boolean_permission;
    boolean boolean_save;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<String> selectedImagesList;
    String targetPdf;

    DisplayPreviewAdapter displayPreviewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_preview);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        selectedImagesList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedArray");
        fn_permission();
        imagesLV = findViewById(R.id.imagesLV);

        displayPreviewAdapter = new DisplayPreviewAdapter(this, selectedImagesList);
        imagesLV.setAdapter(displayPreviewAdapter);

        fabPDF = findViewById(R.id.fabPDF);
        fabPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (boolean_save) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PDFViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("pdfFile", targetPdf);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    if (boolean_permission) {
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayPreview.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
                        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(imagesLV, imagesLV.getWidth(), imagesLV.getHeight());
                        makePDF();

                    } else {

                    }

                    makePDF();
                }
            }
        });


    }


    private void makePDF() {

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;

//        Resources mResources = getResources();
//        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, R.drawable.img_1);

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(getBitmapFromView(imagesLV), convertWidth, convertHighet, true);
//        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);


        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

        document.finishPage(page);


        // write the document content
//        String targetPdf = "/sdcard/test.pdf";
        targetPdf = "mnt/sdcard/testing_1.pdf";
        File filePath = new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            boolean_save = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // close the document
        document.close();
    }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }


    private void fn_permission() {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(DisplayPreview.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DisplayPreview.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(DisplayPreview.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DisplayPreview.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }
        } else {
            boolean_permission = true;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                boolean_permission = true;


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Just integrate `itextpdf` and create table and cell dynamically and add image in each cell.

Comment: Can you say it via programatically

Comment: Please check my below answer to display multiple images in pdf

Comment: possibly answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565602/2900893

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a pdf file in android programmatically and writing in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296149/creating-a-pdf-file-in-android-programmatically-and-writing-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of Struggle I found my own answer in creating multiple pages in a single PDF using android also image annotating with text here is the following source code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DisplayPreview extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = DisplayPreview.class.getName();

    ListView imagesLV;

    FloatingActionButton fabPDF;

    Bitmap anImage;

    TextView tv_link;
    ImageView iv_image;
    LinearLayout ll_pdflayout;
    public static int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    boolean boolean_permission;
    boolean boolean_save;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<String> selectedImagesList;
    String targetPdf;

    DisplayPreviewAdapter displayPreviewAdapter;
    String familyStatus, userNameStr;



    public static final Integer[] IMAGES = {
            R.drawable.img_1,
            R.drawable.img_2,
            R.drawable.img_3,
            R.drawable.img_4,
            R.drawable.img_5,
            R.drawable.img_6,
            R.drawable.img_7
//            ,R.drawable.img_8,
//            R.drawable.img_9
    };

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_preview);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        selectedImagesList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedArray");
        familyStatus = intent.getStringExtra("familyStatus");
        userNameStr = intent.getStringExtra("userNameStr");



        targetPdf = "mnt/sdcard/testing_2.pdf";

        imagesLV = findViewById(R.id.imagesLV);

        displayPreviewAdapter = new DisplayPreviewAdapter(this, selectedImagesList, IMAGES);
//        imagesLV.setAdapter(displayPreviewAdapter);

        fabPDF = findViewById(R.id.fabPDF);

        Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_1);
        anImage = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

        createMultiPagePDF();

        fabPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (boolean_save) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PDFViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("pdfFile", targetPdf);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    if (boolean_permission) {
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayPreview.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
//                        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(imagesLV, imagesLV.getWidth(), imagesLV.getHeight());
                        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(imagesLV, imagesLV.getWidth(), imagesLV.getHeight());
//                        makePDF();

                        createMultiplePDF();
                    } else {

                    }

                    createMultiplePDF();
//                    makePDF();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void createMultiPagePDF() {

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayPreview.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...Creating Invitation");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity

                if (boolean_save) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PDFViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("pdfFile", targetPdf);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    if (boolean_permission) {
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayPreview.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
//                        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(imagesLV, imagesLV.getWidth(), imagesLV.getHeight());
                        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(imagesLV, imagesLV.getWidth(), imagesLV.getHeight());
//                        makePDF();

                        createMultiplePDF();
                    } else {

                    }

                    createMultiplePDF();
//                    makePDF();
                }
            }
        }, 4000);
    }


    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                boolean_permission = true;

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }


    public void createMultiplePDF() {

//        targetPdf = "mnt/sdcard/testing_1.pdf";
        targetPdf = "mnt/sdcard/" + userNameStr + ".pdf";
        File filePath = new File(targetPdf);

//        Document document = new Document();
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        try {

            Drawable myDrawable = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedImagesList.size(); i++) {
//

                String imagePath = selectedImagesList.get(i).replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
                Log.i(TAG, "Image Path is :: 271 :: " + imagePath);

//                if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_8")) {
                if (imagePath.equals(userNameStr)) {

                    Bitmap processedBitmap = ProcessingBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    processedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));


//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);

                }
                if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_2")) {
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_2);

                    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));

//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);
                }
                if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_3")) {
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_3);

                    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));

//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);
                }
                if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_4")) {
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_4);

                    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));

//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);
                }
                if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_5")) {
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_5);

                    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));

//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);
                }
                if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_6")) {
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_6);

                    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));

//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);
                }
                if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_7")) {
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_7);

                    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));

//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);
                }
              /*  if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_8")) {
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_8);

                    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));

//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);
                } if (imagePath.equals("R.drawable.img_9")) {
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_9);

                    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    float hight = (float) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2) * (1.1));
                    float width = (float) ((displaymetrics.widthPixels / 2) * (1.6));

//                    myImg.scaleToFit(hight, width);
                    myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.ARCH_A);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    document.add(myImg);
                    writer.setPageEmpty(false);
                }*/


            }
            document.close();

            pDialog.dismiss();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PDFViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pdfFile", targetPdf);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private Bitmap ProcessingBitmap() {

        Resources resources = DisplayPreview.this.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;

        Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_1);


        Bitmap.Config config = bm1.getConfig();
        if (config == null) {
            config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }

//        newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight(), config);
        anImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight(), config);
//            Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
        Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(anImage);

        newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, null);

        String captionString = userNameStr.trim();
        if (captionString != null) {

            TextPaint paintText = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paintText.setColor(R.color.wedding_guest_name);
            paintText.setTextSize(100);
            paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            paintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

            int textWidth = newCanvas.getWidth() - (int) (250 * scale);

            StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(
                    captionString, paintText, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_LEFT, 1.0f, 1.4f, false);


            Rect rectText = new Rect();
            paintText.getTextBounds(captionString, 0, captionString.length(), rectText);

            float xPos = (newCanvas.getWidth() / 2.16f);
            float yPos = (int) ((newCanvas.getHeight() / 2.4) - ((paintText.descent() + paintText.ascent()) / 3.0));

            float x = newCanvas.getWidth()/2;
//            float y = newCanvas.getHeight()/2;

            // draw text to the Canvas center
            newCanvas.save();
//            newCanvas.translate(xPos, yPos);
            newCanvas.translate(x, yPos);



            textLayout.draw(newCanvas);
            newCanvas.restore();


//            drawMultiLineText(captionString,xPos, yPos, paintText, newCanvas);


//            newCanvas.drawText(captionString,xPos, yPos, paintText);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "caption empty!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //        return newBitmap;
        return anImage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use iTextPdf to create pdf in easy way

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

Comment: Yes I integrated above thing in gradle

Comment: if you want to create pdf for whole view than put that view into NestedView, you can create screenshot of whole view using  private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int height, int width) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }    and put this image into your pdf

Answer (score 0):

Add `itextpdf` library into your project `app build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.5'
```

Below is the code to create pdf file and add image into each cell in table

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
try {

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/*foldername*");
    f = new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + * filename *);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdir();
    }

    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + * filename * +".pdf"));

    document.open();

    for (int l = 0; l < list.size; l++) {
        PdfPTable thirdPart = new PdfPTable(col);
        thirdPart.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        thirdPart.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);
        thirdPart.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

        Image str = list.get(l);
        PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell(str);
        thirdPart.addCell(imageCell);
    }
    document.add(thirdPart);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

document.close();
```