# How to save PDF into Documents in external storage in Android 30?

Tags: android

How to save pdf files in default Documents folder in external storage of the android?

I have tried with:

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
       intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
       intent.setType("application/pdf");
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, name);
       startActivityForResult(intent,PDF_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But this opens another Document provider activity with save option. I want that the pdf file saves directly into Document folder from a single click on my application.

Comment: You want download pdf file ?

Comment: @chandmohd I have a PDFDocument type variable with PDF in it , which I want to save as PDF in Documents. Basically I want to save a variable as PDF in Documents folder.

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296149/creating-a-pdf-file-in-android-programmatically-and-writing-in-it

Comment: Did you try writing there directly using filesystem APIs? The documentation sucks, but [you can write to some locations directly on Android 11](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154750665#comment8). If that does not work, though, then you will either need to [try `MediaStore`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/02/15/scoped-storage-stories-undocumented-documents.html) or settle for the approach from your question.

Comment: @abed That post is 4 years ago and all of its solution uses getExternalStorageDirectory which is now deprecated. Any other solution?

Comment: @CommonsWare Your answer seems to be good. I am testing it and will response here if it works.